# JApplet Program: error: ')' expected, error: illegal start of type, <identifier> expected, error: ';' expected

Tags: java, identifier, illegalstateexception

Code:

```
import java.awt.*; 

import javax.swing.*; 

import java.awt.event.*; 

public class DoubleIt extends JApplet implements actionListener { 

         JLable lValue; 

         JTextField tValue; 

         JButton bDoubble; 

 public void init(){ 
        setSize(200,400);
        Container panel;
        panel = getContent.Pane(); 
        panel.setLayout( new FlowLayout());
        lValue = new JLable("Int Value"); 
        tValue = new Jtextfield(15);
        tValue.SetText("125"); 
        panel.add(lValue); 
        panel.add(tValue); 
        bDoubble = new JButton("*"); 
        panel.add(bDoubble); 
        bDoubble.add.ActionListiner(this); 
        }//end init 

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event); 
        int value; 
        value = Integer.parseInt(tValue.getText()); 
        value = value * 2; 
        tValue.setText(" "+value); 
        }//end method 
     }//end main
```

Errors:

DoubleIt.java:27: error: identifier expected

```
        value = Integer.parseInt(tValue.getText()); 
             ^
```

DoubleIt.java:28: error: identifier expected

```
        value = value * 2; 
             ^
```

DoubleIt.java:29: error: identifier expected

```
        tValue.setText(" "+value); 
                      ^
```

DoubleIt.java:29: error: illegal start of type

```
       tValue.setText(" "+value); 
                       ^
```

DoubleIt.java:29: error: ')' expected

```
        tValue.setText(" "+value); 
                          ^
```

DoubleIt.java:29: error: ';' expected

```
        tValue.setText(" "+value); 
                           ^
```

DoubleIt.java:29: error: illegal start of type

```
        tValue.setText(" "+value); 
                                ^
```

DoubleIt.java:29: error: identifier expected

```
              tValue.setText(" "+value); 
                                 ^
```

DoubleIt.java:29: error: ';' expected

```
        tValue.setText(" "+value); 
                                  ^
```

My Question:

I have all thing things the compiler says I'm missing, is this a bracket issue?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event); <--- See the semi colen...
```

It should be..

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
```

And...

```
JLable lValue;
//...
lValue = new JLable("Int Value");
```

should be...

```
JLabel lValue;
//...
lValue = new JLabel("Int Value");
```

And...

```
tValue = new Jtextfield(15);
```

should be...

```
tValue = new JTextField(15);
```

And...

```
tValue.SetText("125");
```

should be...

```
tValue.setText("125");
```

And...

```
bDoubble.add.ActionListiner(this);
```

should be...

```
bDoubble.addActionListener(this);
```

And...

```
public class DoubleIt extends JApplet implements actionListener
```

should be...

```
public class DoubleIt extends JApplet implements ActionListener
```

And...

```
panel = getContent.Pane();
```

should be...

```
panel = getContentPane();
```

Remember, Java is case sensitive, case matters

Comment: First: Thank you for your time. Second: now I'm getting a new variety of issues.

Comment: they mostly now involve not finding symbols in the other two sections of the code.

Comment: Chao, you should mark Mad's answer as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event);
```

To

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you've put a semicolon after your method declaration:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event);
```

Replace the `;` with an `{` (opening brace)